# mat-select dropdown with no wrap - how can I change the position? (Angular Material 15+)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to make the option of a mat-select so they don't wrap. I was able to do by using the following CSS, but the overlay of the dropdown doesn't move accordingly.

```
  .mat-mdc-select-panel {
    min-width: fit-content !important;

    .mat-mdc-option {
      .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
        color: mat.get-color-from-palette($foreground, primary-text);
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: visible;
        text-overflow: unset;
      }
   }
```

But then the overlay panel doesn't seem to aknowledge these changes and show the panel outside the page as can be seen from the image below.

[image]

Is there any way to reposition the overlay so that the correct width is calculated or perhaps change the point where the overlay is anchored?

Here's a screenshot using the inspect mode:

[image]

Comment: With v16.1 you will be able to use the new `panelWidth` parameter, see the [docs](https://next.material.angular.io/components/select/api). However this feature is not included in a stable release yet.

Comment: @JSONDerulo Sadly I cannot upgrade to 16 for a while so that's not really an option, but thank you for the info!